# Mongo DB configuration not working when loaded

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have the following mongo db configuration for spring framework:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />

<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" username="admin" password="abc" dbname="test123"
    mongo-ref="mongo" />
<!-- <mongo:db-factory dbname="test123" /> -->

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

However when I start up spring framework it doesn't seems like it is connecting to the test123 database. And it is connecting to the default test database. Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the xml to following xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

 <!-- Default bean name is 'mongo' -->
 <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" />

 <bean id="mongoTemplate"
 class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
 <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
 <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test123" />

 </bean>

 <!-- To translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
 <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```